# return results only containing text

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm attempting to call the Google Calendar API and return results only containing a specific piece of text.

Using the following snippet:

```
    eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary', timeMin=start_time, timeMax=end_time, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
```

I receive results in the following format:

```
(u'2018-02-16', u'Foo')
(u'2018-02-16T10:00:00-07:00', u'Bar')
```

I am attempting to add logic to limit results to those lines containing 'Foo'

```
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        if "Foo" in event:
            print(start, event['summary'])
```

Returns nothing.

Do I need to place the `if "Foo" in event:` logic elsewhere? Am I misunderstanding the usage?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, wouldn't it be `if "Foo" in event['summary']:`? It might be easier to tell if you showed a sample of a full "event" (print it to show all key/value pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[dict.values](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm)** method to check for value.

**Ex:**

```
if "Foo" in event.values():
    print(start, event['summary'])
```

Comment: Nope. That also returns nothing. 

I noticed that my results are coming back in Unicode. 

`(u'2018-02-16', u'Foo')
(u'2018-02-16T10:00:00-07:00', Bar')`

I'm not quite clear on how to strip those fields from the results, or if they are causing issues with the if statement.

Comment: I figured it out. The values were being stored in a list. I made the following changes:

```
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('date')
        summary = event['summary']

        if 'foo' in event['summary']:
            print(start, summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, events was a list. I was able to make the following changes to only output the results matching the 'foo' in the list:

```
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('date')
    summary = event['summary']

    if 'foo' in event['summary']:
        print(start, summary)
```